# Want to transform XML having mixed content

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

My XML is like below , I want to convert it to mentioned expected xml format using XSLT 2.0. `child1` and `child2` are just samples, in actual XML there can be several such node with different names. I am a  very beginner to XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<properties xmlns="http://www.sss.org">
My Parent level text 1 <b> i am bold</b> not bold
<child1>
text1 of first child
<child1val attribute1="testval">36-37</child1val>
text2 of child <sub> subscript</sub>
</child1>    
<child2>
text1 of first child2
<child2val attribute1="testval">444</child2val>
<child2val>555</child2val>
text2 of child2
</child2>
My Parent level text3 in  <b> i am bold</b>
</properties>
```

expected result:

```
<properties xmlns="http://www.sss.org">
<text>
 My Parent level text 1 <b> i am bold</b> not bold
</text>
<child1>
<text> text1 of first child </text>
<child1val attribute1="testval">36-37</child1val>
<text> text2 of child <i> i m italic</i></text>
</child1>    
<child2>
<text> text1 of second child2</text>
<child2val attribute1="testval">444</child2val>
<child2val>555</child2val>
<text> text2 of child2</text>
</child2>
My Parent level text3 in  <b> i am bold</b>
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you have indented your XML doesn't help with how you have asked the question. For example, consider this abridged sample of your XML.

```
<properties>
My Parent level text 1 <b> i am bold</b> not bold
<child1>
text1 of first child
</child1>    
</properties>
```

The way it is laid out seems to imply the **properties** element has two children. But it doesn't, it has four children. More clear indentation would be like this

```
<properties>
   My Parent level text 1 
   <b> i am bold</b> 
   not bold
   <child1>
      text1 of first child
   </child1>    
</properties>
```

And it looks like the **text** element only needs to surround the first three children, but not the **child1** element. It is not clear why **b** gets surround in the **text** element, but **child1** doesn't, but I am guessing it is because **b** and **i** (and **sub**?) are 'html' elements, but **child1** is not.

Making that assumption, you can probably solve this using the **xsl:for-each-group** command in XSLT 2.0, together with its **group-adjacent** attribute. You are grouping adjacent nodes if they are text nodes, or **b** or **i** or **sub**, so the command would look like this

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="node()" 
                    group-adjacent="boolean(self::b|self::i|self::sub|self::text())">
```

Within this, you can then check the **current-grouping-key()** function to determine whether you then need to surround the group with a **text** element

```
    <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
          <text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
          </text>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
       </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

This code itself probably only needs to run for elements that have other elements as children, and not for elements that just have a single text node as a child. This means it would live in a template with this match

```
<xsl:template match="*[*]">
```

Other nodes would be matched and copied with the XSLT [identity template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform).

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.sss.org" xmlns="http://www.sss.org">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="*[*]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="boolean(self::b|self::i|self::sub|self::text())">
        <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
              <text>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
              </text>
           </xsl:when>
           <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
           </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose> 
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(Note the use of namespaces here, as all the elements in your XML are in a namespace).

This should output the following

```
<properties xmlns="http://www.sss.org">
   <text>
      My Parent level text 1 <b> i am bold</b> not bold
   </text>
   <child1>
      <text>
        text1 of first child
      </text>
      <child1val attribute1="testval">36-37</child1val>
      <text>
         text2 of child <sub> subscript</sub>
      </text>
   </child1>
   <child2>
      <text>
        text1 of first child2
      </text>
      <child2val attribute1="testval">444</child2val>
      <child2val>555</child2val>
      <text>
         text2 of child2
      </text>
   </child2>
   <text>
      My Parent level text3 in  <b> i am bold</b>
   </text>
</properties>
```